# How can I know which string chunk is executed in c# - luainterface?

Tags: c#, lua, luainterface

I am running on C# - lua project. The project has all logic in lua part, and c# part holds the built-in console to display result and take input. So debugging is almost occurred in lua part. My lua codes looks like below:

```
[lua]
#region main
1  foo(blah)
2  bar(blah) -- bad argument, will provoke error
#end

#region functionsholder
1  function foo(argument)
2    --do something
3  end
4  function bar(argument)
5    --do something with argument.
6  end
#end
```

then in my project, c# holds two string chunks, namely main and functionsholder. Then my c# code runs as below:

```
[c#]
1   public void runscript(string name)
2   try
3   {
4       lua.Dostring(name);
5   }
6   catch (LuaException e)
7   {
8       Console.Writeline("An unhandled exception occured at string chunk " + name + ".");
9       Console.WriteLine(e);
10  }
11  runscript("functionsholder"); // need to load functions first.
12  runscript("main"); // start main code block, and by above, this result in exception.
```

The problem(which I think) is the log message.

```
An unhandled exception occured at string chunk main.
LuaInterface.LuaException: [string "chunk"]:5: bad argument #1 to 'pairs' (table expected, got nil)
   위치: LuaInterface.Lua.ThrowExceptionFromError(Int32 oldTop)
   위치: LuaInterface.Lua.DoString(String chunk)
   위치: SomeProject.SomeClass.runscript(String name) 파일 d:\Git\SomeSolution\SomeProject\SomeClass.cs:줄 4
```

To debug this code, i think it is important to know where the code fails. However I cannot get proper information because LuaException only give the information of line number, and not chunk name. My error handling code gives a chunk name, but it is useless because exception is thrown in other chunk.

Thank you for your patience to read this so far and my question is here(and obvious): How can I get proper error message to look into? I want two information, which are 1) line number of exception thrown. 2) string chunk name to which the exact line belongs.

Comment: Please show how are you loading the chunks. Also the exception seems to be from an older version of the code and doesn't its .NET stack trace have more lines?

Comment: @TomBlodget I feel it is difficult to describe how I am loading the chunks: [link](https://github.com/BaalDL/CruiserConsole/blob/master/CruiserConsole/DataLoader.cs) the loadScript method does it. I didn't check .NET stack trace here, but I want to make it possible to debug without VS debugger for future user who only edits lua codes. And what do you mean by the older version of the code?

Comment: Was `SomeProject.SomeClass.executeFunction` renamed to `runscript`?

Comment: @TomBlodget exactly. Sorry for inconvenience: I'll make it clear for further study on this problem.